# Inventory system theory

Tags: inventory

I am working on a point & click adventure game, similar to the LucasArts games from the 90s. 
I want to make an inventory system in which you can click on an item on screen and then that item will appear in one of the free slots in the interface and when you use/give that item, the slot has to become free again. (you shouldn't be able to store more than one item on one slot)

I've tried to do it, but I got confused and just couldn't figure out how to properly do this.

Can someone give me the basic theory, idea of doing this? I don't want to know any code, just a simplified explanation so I can understand the basic idea and build upon that.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure if I've understood your question. When the stage starts, a list of available objects are positioned randomly and when someone click on it, it's tagged and then it's only available to who grabbed it first. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, 

I want to make an interface with 7 available slots. If you click on an object in the scene (something that's needed to progress further in the story/game) I want that item to appear in the first available slot. When another item is picked up, I want that item to appear in another slot. When one of the items is used, I want to destroy the item from the interface and make that slot available again. When the player clicks on an item when all the slots are full, a message should pop up telling the player that all slots are full.

Comment: Looks like before adding items to the slots, you have to first check it there's room for it. Some interfaces such as "UFO enemy unknown" allow you to have objects with different sizes too (one object may take 3 slots for example) and you could also assign a weight to each object and calculate if your character is strong enough to carry it (still not sure if I am helping)